# How to iterate through a directory to overwrite a file?

Tags: c#

I have a directory path that is already created in the user profiles.
The code below creates the directories and the customize.xml is copied into the Customize folder. This code creates folders rather than just drilling down into the userprofile and all sub-directories. I just need the Customize folder to be overwritten or just the Customize.xml file to be added to it and overwrite the one that may already be there. How do I do this?

```
string fileName = "Customize.xml"; 
string targetPath = @"\\desktoppath\c$\%USERPROFILE%\%APPDATA%\%Roaming%\%Litera%\Customize";
//string targetPath = @"\\desktoppath\c$\TestFolder";
// Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

// To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
// Create a new target folder, if necessary.
if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
```

Comment: [`System.IO.File.Copy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)?

Comment: Here are the problems with this question... you say "*The code below creates the directories **and the file I need is copied into the Customize folder**"* What file? there is no copy here. *"The problem is that I don't need the folders created"* what do you mean?  you are only creating one "*I just need the Customize folder to be overwritten and the Customize.xml file to be added to it from a different location*" what customizw folder? *"added to it from a different location"* what location ? .... please reword this, add more information and be specif, this is very ambiguous, i am guessing

Answer (score 0):

This is just only something:

```
string fileNamenameToCopy = "D:\\Folder1\\Customize.xml"; 
File.Copy(fileNamenameToCopy, targetPath+ "\\Customize.xml");
```

Comment: While that works targetpath is defined by the following: string targetPath = @"\\workstation\c$\USERPROFILE\APPDATA\Roaming\Litera\Customize"; it's possible that I am not explaining this clear enough. I need to copy the customize.xml to all user files when they log in. However, what I have defined as the  targetPath creates a folder USERPROFILE and all subfolders. I don't need it to do that. I just want the targetPath to be the Customize folder (that already exists) and to place the customize.xml in that folder and overwrite any current one that may be there.